# Flask app to administrate network interfaces

Tags: python, linux, flask

I made a Flask app that consists of 3 pages.

- Index: Indexes to the 2 pages
- SubnetOverview: SSH's into the server and executes `ifconfig`, then returns the output to a webpage.
- AddSubnet: Has a HTML form where the administrator can fill in the desired VLAN id and subnet. This gets added to the `netplan` file and `netplan apply` gets executed to apply the changes.

```
    #Flask app that interacts with a router running on a virtual machine, enbales administrator to list current network interfaces and make a new subinterface via SSH.
```

`from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import paramiko
import ssl

app = Flask(__name__)

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.load_cert_chain('certificates/cert.pem', 'certificates/key.pem')

SERVER_IP = "192.168.0.80"
SERVER_USERNAME = "root"
SERVER_PASSWORD = "secret123"
SERVER_PORT = 22
SERVER_IFCONFIG = "/sbin/ifconfig"

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/SubnetOverview')
def SubnetOverview():
    #Try to SSH into the server and execute the command
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(SERVER_IP, port=SERVER_PORT, username=SERVER_USERNAME, password=SERVER_PASSWORD)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(SERVER_IFCONFIG, get_pty=True)
    output = stdout.readlines()
    output = ''.join(output)
    output = output.replace("\r\n", "<br />")
    client.close()
    return render_template('SubnetOverview.html', ssh_output=output)

@app.route('/AddSubnet', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def AddSubnet():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #Getting the data from the HTML form
        formdata = request.form.to_dict()
        vlanid = formdata.get('vlanid')
        address = formdata.get('address')
        command = "    vlan" + vlanid + ":\n      id: " + vlanid + "\n      link: eth0\n      addresses: [ \"" + address + "\" ]\n"
        #Opening an SFTP connection
        transport = paramiko.Transport((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
        transport.connect(username=SERVER_USERNAME, password=SERVER_PASSWORD)
        sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
        file=sftp.file('/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml', "a", -1)
        file.write(command)
        file.flush()
        SERVER_COMMAND = "sudo netplan apply"
        sftp.close()
        transport.close()
        #Opening SSH connection to send a command that apply's the config
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(SERVER_IP, port=SERVER_PORT, username=SERVER_USERNAME, password=SERVER_PASSWORD)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(SERVER_COMMAND, get_pty=True)
        client.close()
        return redirect("/SubnetOverview")
    return render_template('AddSubnet.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=443, ssl_context=context)`